# Hive parquet snappy compression not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, parquet, snappy

I am creating one table skeleton using the table properties as 
`TBLPROPERTIES('PARQUET.COMPRESSION'='SNAPPY')`
(as the files are in parquet format) and setting few of the parameters before creating the table as :

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set parquet.enable.dictionary=false;
set hive.plan.serialization.format=javaXML;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
set avro.output.codec=snappy;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
add jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p1168.923/lib/sentry/lib/hive-metastore.jar;
```

Still the table is not getting compressed. Could you please let me know the reason for table not getting compressed.

Thanks in advance for you inputs.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is using `“TBLPROPERTIES ('parquet.compression'='SNAPPY')”`(and the case matters) in the DDL instead of `“TBLPROPERTIES ('PARQUET.COMPRESSION'='SNAPPY')”.`

You can also achieve the compression using the following property in the hive.

```
set parquet.compression=SNAPPY
```

Comment: In a addition, If you are useing CDH, you can verify the compression in the following way => /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/parquet/bin/parquet-tools meta  you_table_data_file.

Answer (score 1):

Your Parquet table is probably compressed but you're not directly seeing that. In Parquet files, the compression is baked in into the format. Instead of the whole file being compressed, individual segments are compressed using the specified algorithm. Thus a compressed Parquet will look from the outside the same as a compressed one (normally they don't include any suffix like normal compressed files have (e.g. `.gz`) as you cannot decompress them using the usual tools).

Having the compression baked in into the format is one of the many advantages of the Parquet format. This makes the files (hadoop-)splittable independent of the compression algorithm as well as it enables fast access to specific segments of the file without the need to decompress the whole file. In the case of a query engine processing a query on top of Parquet files, this means that often it only needs to read the small but uncompressed header, sees which segments are relevant for the query and then only needs to decompress these relevant sections.

Comment: The reason that I am saying the tables is not compressed is because I know the compressed table size. The table which is getting created is no where close to that size. Any parameter which I am missing or wrongly put?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created some tables stored as Parquet file with Snappy compression and have used the following commands:

```
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true;
set hive.intermediate.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
set hive.intermediate.compression.type=BLOCK;
```

Comment: I tried with the above mentioned set commands as well but still its not getting compressed.

Comment: How you are checking that your table is compressed or not?

Comment: I am checking using the parquet-tools.jar with meta and its showing uncompressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set the below parameters and after that perform below steps-

SET parquet.compression=SNAPPY; 
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;

CREATE TABLE Test_Parquet ( 
    customerID int, name string, ..etc 
) STORED AS PARQUET Location ''

INSERT INTO Test_Parquet SELECT * FROM Test;

If not how do i identify a parquet table with snappy compression and parquet table without snappy compression?.

describe formatted tableName

Note  -  but you will always see the compression as NO because the compression data format is not stored in 
metadata of the table , the best way is to do dfs  -ls -r  to the table location and see the file format for compression.

Note- Currently the default compression is - Snappy with Impala tables. 


If your issue didn't resolved after these steps also please post the all steps which are you performing..?
```

Comment: I am already using these commands before creating the table but still no luck. What else can be the issue?

Comment: did you check dfs  -ls -r  to the table location and see the file format for compression.

Comment: what is the expected output of this command if the files are snappy compressed?

Comment: I created table and i also performed all steps, when i am using describe formatted table_name. It's showing                                                     
  Table Parameters:    
 COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE true                
 PARQUET.COMPRESSION  SNAPPY              
 numFiles             1                   
 numRows              0                   
 rawDataSize          0                   
 totalSize            143                 
 transient_lastDdlTime 1516713741

Comment: I am also seeing the same things in my desc formatted table. But the parquet-tools.jar meta output shows the files are not compressed.

Answer (score 0):

I see this mistake being done several times, here is what needs to be done (This will only work for hive. NOT with SPARK) :

OLD PROPERTY     :

> TBLPROPERTIES('PARQUET.COMPRESSION'='SNAPPY')

CORRECT PROPERTY :

> TBLPROPERTIES('PARQUET.COMPRESS'='SNAPPY')

Comment: this worked for me 
    TBLPROPERTIES('PARQUET.COMPRESSION'='SNAPPY'). But I needed to add one more set command which is set parquet.compression=snappy;

Comment: I tried this suggestion and its still not working, can you check what am I doing wrong here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064376/how-can-insert-into-a-hive-table-with-parquet-fileformat-and-snappy-compression.

Comment: @annunarcist Are you using "hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.6.0.jar meta <parquetFile>" to check if the compression is working ?

Comment: Yep! For some reason, It is only after set parquet.compression=snappy;, I got it compressed.