# Difference between 'parquet.compress' and 'parquet.compression' in hive table properties

Tags: apache-spark, hive, compression, parquet, cloudera

I am trying to find the documentation and info about using Hive tables with compressed parquet files. I have seen that it is possible to add a table property like this:

```
TBLPROPERTIES ('parquet.compress[ion]'='SNAPPY')
```

the problem is that in some places I find 'parquet.compress', and in some other places I see 'parquet.compression'. For example, this question has both as answers:
[Hive parquet snappy compression not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395999/hive-parquet-snappy-compression-not-working)

and it is not clear to me when to use each (which versions support each, for example...)

Any docs or info I can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct property name is "parquet.compression".

See source codes: [ParquetOutputFormat](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetOutputFormat.java) class contains COMPRESSION constant with property name:

```
* # The compression algorithm used to compress pages
 * parquet.compression=UNCOMPRESSED # one of: UNCOMPRESSED, SNAPPY, GZIP, LZO. Default: UNCOMPRESSED. Supersedes mapred.output.compress*

...

public static final String COMPRESSION = "parquet.compression";
```

Also [ParquetRecordWriterWrapper](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/parquet/write/ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.java) class uses table property using the same constant ParquetOutputFormat.COMPRESSION, which is "parquet.compression":

```
String compressionName = tableProperties.getProperty(ParquetOutputFormat.COMPRESSION);
```

Read also [Cloudera Parquet format documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/cdh_ig_parquet.html#parquet_format).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot for the info!

Comment: @Selnay   In cloudera docs it is also mentioned as parquet.compression, added link

Comment: thanks for the link as well. Checking the parquet repo I was able to find also this javadoc with relevant info: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.parquet/parquet-hadoop/latest/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetOutputFormat.html